# How can I list the contents of a folder inside sharedwithme using google drive api?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I am trying to list the contents of a folder under google drive using API v2 (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) but I cant seem to work out how to go about it.

I am trying :

```
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'maxResults': 50,
      'q': '<ID OF FOLDER> in sharedWithMe'
    })
```

Invalid Query.

To output the sharedWithMe folder I can do this ...

```
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'maxResults': 50,
      'q': 'sharedWithMe'
    })
```

And it works but I want to only show the contents of the one folder inside shared with me. (0Bwfn1xwP3jS_b2VlRUp4SjcwOGc) is the id of this folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer was to enclose the id in ""'s and to list in parent.

eg

```
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'maxResults': 100,
      'q': '"<ID OF FOLDER>" in parents'
    })
```